# If $f$ is an odd function, show that $f(0)=f''(0)=f''''(0)=....=0$

Tags: calculus, functions

If $f$ is an odd function, show that $f(0)=f''(0)=f''''(0)=....=0$
and if $f$ is an even function, show that $f'(0)=f'''(0)=f'''''(0)=...0$
I do know why $f''(0)$ of an odd function is zero and why $f'(0)$ of an even function is zero, but I can't go any further(ex. Why f''''(0) is also zero, etc).

Comment: Consider its MacLaurin polynomial, and deduce that many coefficient must vanish.

Comment: If you know that $f''(0)$ is even, just note that $f''$ again is an odd function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Using the chain rule: $\frac{d}{dx} f(-x) = - f'(-x)$. From here, if $f$ is an odd function: $$- f'(-x) = \frac{d}{dx} f(-x) = \frac{d}{dx} (-f(x)) = - f'(x) \implies f'(-x) = f'(x)$$
and if $f$ is an even function 
$$
- f'(-x) = \frac{d}{dx} f(-x) = \frac{d}{dx} f(x) = f'(x) \implies f'(-x) = - f'(x).
$$
This shows that the derivative of an odd function is an even function and that the derivative of an even function is an odd function.